# Apply a list of functions to a single matrix and retain the function names

Tags: r

My ultimate goal is to collect a list of summary stats for the columns of a `data.frame` or a `matrix`. For example, if I had a `data.frame` with three variables/columns I might want to know the mean, median and standard deviation of each column. What I would like to do is have a function that takes an arbitrary list of functions. I know something like this will do the trick

```
summarise = function(x, stats = list(mean, median, sd, length)){
     lapply(stats, function(stat){apply(x, 2, stat)})
}
```

but how can I label the elements of the results with the name of the statistic/function applied? For example, if `x` is

```
x = matrix(1:9, nc = 3)
```

then how could I write my function `summarise` so that I get

```
> summarise(x)
$mean
[1] 2 5 8

$median
[1] 2 5 8

$sd
[1] 1 1 1

$length
[1] 3 3 3
```

back as the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple option is to have a named output in the OP's `summarise` function

```
summarise <- function(x, stats = list(mean = mean, median = median,
       sd = sd, length = length)){
         lapply(stats, function(stat){apply(x, 2, stat)})
   }

summarise(x)
#$mean
#[1] 2 5 8

#$median
#[1] 2 5 8

#$sd
#[1] 1 1 1

#$length
#[1] 3 3 3
```

---

Or if we use `dplyr::lst` or `purrr::lst`, it would automatically rename the `list` elements

```
summarise <- function(x, stats = dplyr::lst(mean, median,
       sd, length)){
         lapply(stats, function(stat){apply(x, 2, stat)})
   }

summarise(x)
#$mean
#[1] 2 5 8

#$median
#[1] 2 5 8

#$sd
#[1] 1 1 1

#$length
#[1] 3 3 3
```